# jslint.com | Does not recognize localStorage

Tags: javascript, jslint

Getting error:

```
'localStorage' was used before it was defined.
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

`localStorage` is available on all modern browsers and as far as I know does not need to be defined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any global that you want to appear as defined to jslint can be defined in a comment of globals.  E.g.:

```
/*global localStorage: false, console: false, $: false */
```

This would make localStorage, console, and $ (jQuery) not trigger that warning.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't know how the code will be used.  You need to set the browser option.  Note this is default in jshint.com but not jslint.com